# Best constant integer inequality

Tags: inequality, natural-numbers

Suppose $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are positive integers. Trivially one has that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \leq \left (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2
$$
I am wondering whether it is possible to make it somehow sharper, i.e. find some constant $0<C<1$ and $D>0$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \leq C \left (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2 - D.
$$
Any comment/idea/counterexample is more than welcome!

Answer (score 5):

No, since when all but one of the $a_i$ are $0$, we have equality.

Edit: You state specifically that the $a_i$ are positive integers. Setting $a_2=\cdots=a_n=1$ gives a counterexample for sufficiently large $a_1$, since
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2=(a_1+n-1)^2=a_1^2+2a_i(n-1)+(n-1)^2$$
and the ratio of this to 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_1+(n-1)$$
goes to $1$ as $a_1\to\infty$.

Comment: ... but the integers do not contain sufficiently small positive $\epsilon < 1$

Comment: @martini Well, it seems I cannot read. I'll fix that.

Comment: what about the constant $D$?

Comment: @AleZok Even $D=0$ does not work, so certainly $D>0$ does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1 = k$ and $a_i = 1$ for $i \ge 2$. Then the left hand side equals 
$$ L := k^2 + (n-1) $$
and the right hand side
$$ R := \bigl(k + (n-1)\bigr)^2 = k^2 + 2k(n-1) + (n-1)^2 $$
Now for $k \to \infty$
$$ \frac RL = \frac{k^2 + 2k(n-1) + (n-1)^2}{k^2 + (n-1)} \to 1 $$
That is, there is no such $C$.

---

For $D$, note that
\begin{align*}
  R &= \left(\sum_i a_i\right)^2\\
    &= L + \sum_{i\ne j} a_i a_j\\
    &\ge L + \frac{n(n-1)}2
\end{align*}
(Note that $a_ia_j \ge 1$ for every pair $i,j$.

Comment: what about the constant $D$?

Comment: @AleZok Added something